# Arangodb: arangosh get granted databases/users for a given user/database

Tags: database, arangodb

How to get from within arangosh
1) all granted databases for a given user
2) all granted users for a given database
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with AQL.

1) `db._query("FOR u IN _users FILTER u.user == @user FOR db IN ATTRIBUTES(u.databases) FILTER u.databases[db] == 'rw' RETURN db", {"user":"user_name"})`

2) `db._query("FOR u IN _users LET userDbs = (FOR db IN @dbs FILTER u.databases[db] == 'rw' RETURN db) FILTER LENGTH(userDbs) RETURN u.user", {"dbs":["*","database_name","another_database_name"]})`

With the second AQL you can search for users that have access to one of the given databases. A user can have access to all databases (like root user) and not to one explicit. In this case you have to use `*` as database name, like in my example.